# Error retrieving JSON field in a PostgreSQL column Select

Tags: json, postgresql, select

I'm trying to perform a SELECT at a PostgreSQL table with a JSON column. The problem is that that column is not a real JSON.

When I export to CSV the result is the following:

```
"{""access"":""1.SQnGhZKY4cemiRU+Svteoj2ZPQJ74uqXoWmGg0BmVf8ho3D2c7g1xYogcwz"",""objectId"":""58e3a109b48a6"",""deviceId"":""58e65028b4567"",""deviceBusinessUnits"":[],""crmId"":""443-f01246e5"",""crmBusinesUnits"":[],""crm"":{""gender"":""m"",""birthDate"":"""",""age"":null,""customFields"":{""displayName"":""te4"",""givenName"":""test"",""familyName"":""test"",""email"":""tes@yopil.net"",""mobileNumber"":""68"",""mobileNumberCountryCode"":""34"",""residencyCountry"":""LUX"",""mailingStreetName1"":null,""mailingStreetName2"":null,""mailingSubAdministrativeArea"":null,""mailingMunicipality"":null,""mailingPostalCode"":""208"",""mailingAdministrativeArea"":null,""mailingCountry"":null,""shippingStreetName1"":null,""shippingStreetName2"":null,""shippingSubAdministrativeArea"":null,""shippingMunicipality"":null,""shippingPostalCode"":null,""shippingAdministrativeArea"":null,""shippingCountry"":null},""tags"":[],""businessUnits"":[],""crmProvider"":{""type"":""cid"",""sessionToken"":""7drmcvu""}}}"
```

My column is named "user" and my query is:

```
select 
mytable.user ->> 'accessToken' as userRaw
from mytable;
```

But I get:

[image]

How could I get the JSON values from this column?

Comment: what returned if you `select substr(user,1,100) from mytable`?..

Comment: Not direct related to question, but `...as userRaw,` here you don't need  last comma

Comment: @OtoShavadze it was the copy&paste :P Thanks for the comment

Comment: @VaoTsun ERROR:  function substr(json, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select substr(mytable.user,1,100) from mytable
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: from your error, I suppose you should try `select 
mytable.user ->> 'access' as userRaw
from mytable;`